# How do I clear the most recent webview history entry

Tags: android, webview, browser-history

I am building a webview app with buttons to go forward and back in the webveiw history.
The problem is that when I type an url into my search bar, the url that I typed in is added to the history, and then webview requests that page from the web.

For instance web servers that detect my user agent as mobile will supply a different page than what I requested.  This puts my forward/back buttons out of sync.

How can I delete a specific history entry?  What I would do is delete the entry that is just before the returned url so as to delete the typed in url.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
// function to detect when a button is pressed and if it is
  // get the text from the edittext box
  // then condition it to have http attributes
  //
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UrlText);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonClear:
            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            et.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clear link", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonBack:
            if(wv.canGoBack()){
                wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                wv.goBack();
                et.setText(wv.getUrl());
            }
            Toast.makeText(this,"Back",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonHome:
            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            et.setText("www.cnn.com");
            String url = et.getText().toString().trim();
            wv.loadUrl("http://" + url);
            String url1 = wv.getUrl();
            Toast.makeText(this,url1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonForward:
            if(wv.canGoForward()){
                wv.goForward();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this,"Forward",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
```